# How to catch VB6 ADODC Error

Tags: vb6

When I made a connection with ADODC to Access database.mdb That connection is succeed and I can make SQL command through it.

It is OK when I SELECT data .

```
  ADODC1.recordsource="SELECT Name FROM Product"
  ADODC1.refresh
```

But There is an error when I Insert or Update it.

```
  ADODC1.recordsource"INSERT INTO Product (ID,Name,Quantity,Price,Category) VALUES ('" & txtbarcode & "','" & txtname & "','" & txtqty & "','" & txtprice & "','" & category & "')"
  ADODC1.refresh
```

The error msg is "The Operation is not allowed when the object is closed"
I don't why do I get this error. Please help me to catch this error msg or solve it. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Maybe because the insert doesn't return an open recordset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is that the ADO Data Control has a lot of problems like this one.  The easiest way to solve them is to not use it!  I've never used it to insert data before, and after messing around with it I'm going to say that this is a bug in the Refresh method itself.  I set up some code similar to yours, and I find that while it in fact inserts the data successfully, the problem persists.  It also ignores any attempts to disable the error handler with "On Error Resume Next."  So, I would suggest that it's time to learn how to use ADO data objects.

To do what you want, you will need a Connection object and optionally a Command object.  If you don't want to use a Command object, you can just use the Connection's Execute method, but you can't execute stored procedures without using a Command object.  Stored procedures are much more secure than straight SQL statements, so you'll want to use them eventually.  (By the way, since you're not trying to display any data, you won't need a Recordset object.)  So, read up on those two and see if you can get them working.  Trust me, you'll be glad that you went to the trouble.